# How to change the default redirect after click on save button when you add data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Everyone know, when add data by using `grocery-crud`, at end of the page there is a button named save to save the data in database.

This save button when clicked, save the data, then redirect to the data list page.

Now I'm use `$crud->unset_list()` method to unset the data list page.

Thus, when clicked on save button redirect to blank page, and that was the data list page.

**My question:**
How to redirect to a specific page as I want after clicked on save button, instead of redirect to data list page as it was

- **An example of add page**.

[image]
<sub>(source: [grocerycrud.com](https://www.grocerycrud.com/assets/uploads/general/required-fields-message.png))</sub>

- **An example of data list page**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These people seem to be having success using a JavaScript workaround:

http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/324-workaround-redirect-to-the-list-after-insertupdate-without-changing-the-core-functionality-of-gc/

Update:

adding code for answer preservation...

For Insert:

```
$crud->set_lang_string('insert_success_message',
         'Your data has been successfully stored into the database.<br/>Please wait while you are redirecting to the list page.
         <script type="text/javascript">
          window.location = "'.site_url(strtolower(__CLASS__).'/'.strtolower(__FUNCTION__)).'";
         </script>
         <div style="display:none">
         '
   );
```

For Update:

```
$crud->set_lang_string('update_success_message',
     'Your data has been successfully stored into the database.<br/>Please wait while you are redirecting to the list page.
     <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location = "'.site_url(strtolower(__CLASS__).'/'.strtolower(__FUNCTION__)).'";
     </script>
     <div style="display:none">
);
```